# Fade out animation goes to balck and then faded out

Tags: css

My WebPage background is BLUE and I want to create a simple RED blinking circle; But when animation runs, first it turns black and then hides

```css
body {
background: blue;
}
.blinker {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    animation: blink 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinker"></span>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color or https://isle.hanover.edu/Ch06Color/Ch06ColorMixer.html

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're looking for but, I've added black as a background colour with opacity on in the keyframes then it goes to red.
Let me know if its what you wanted.

```css
 body {
background: blue;
}
.blinker {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    animation: blink 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from{
      background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    to {
      background-color: red;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinker"></span>
```